# Python alter external variable from within function

Tags: python

When I run this it works, but it says

```
"name 'select_place' is assigned to before global declaration"
```

When I get rid of the second global, no comment appears, but as select_place is no longer global it is not readable (if selected) in my last line of code. 
I'm really new to python, ideally I'd like a way of not using the global command but after searching i still can't find anything that helps.

My code:

```
def attempt(x):
    if location =='a':
         global select_place
         select_place = 0
   if location =='b'
        global select_place
        select_place = 1

place = ([a,b,c,d])
```

This is the start of some turtle graphics

```
def Draw_piece_a(Top_right):
    goto(place[select_place])
```

Comment: The best way to avoid `global` is to avoid global variables. Why not have `attempt()` explicitly *return* the value of `select_place` instead of using a global?

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the variable first, additionally the function code can be made clearer:

```
select_place = False
def attempt(x):
    global select_place
    if location == 'a':
        select_place = 0
    elif location == 'b':
        select_place = 1
```

Also, there is no return value for `attempt()`, is this what you want?